# Tomcat gives Same Response

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am using ajax for sending request to a servlet using tomcat web server. first i send a request and it gets response from the servlet and then i call the that ajax for send a request to servlet using the same uri, tomcat does not invoke my servlet it send the previous response.

originally what i am do, is that when my page to ajax request is go to servlet after some time its give response to me. when i refresh or re run the application it does not send request object for servlet, tomcat directly send previous reponse to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's not Tomcat that sends you the same response, but your browser cache. Try using a POST instead of a GET, or use [jQuery's `cache` setting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or a similar trick) to prevent caching from the browser.