# Tomcat response the same every time after initital response

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a relatively simple spring web application running on tomcat which returns an xml document.  The initial request goes in and I can debug into my code.  However, subsequent requests do not drop into the debugger.  I can make the initial request with either a browser or soapUI, and subsequent requests (on different browsers/programs/machines) get the same response as the initial one.

The localhost_access_log is getting populated with every request.  However the log4j file is not getting populated beyond the first request.

I'm using Tomcat 7 and spring 3.1.1.  This happens on both the tomcat deployed within eclipse (used to enable debugging), as well as deploying it on another tomcat server on linux.

This is similar to another question ([Tomcat gives Same Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422799/tomcat-gives-same-response) ) which never had an accepted answer.

So it doesn't appear to be browser caching (different applications making requests get the same response), but rather some sort of Tomcat caching.

Any ideas?  Here is the server.xml which I believe may be the cause of the problem somehow, but I don't see any red flags.  Also, I'm doing GETs to the web application, which may be caching somehow on the server side.

Example GET request: `http://localhost:8130/bootstrap/xml?environment=dev`

It returns a xml document as noted in this RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xml", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/xml")
```

Sample Response:

```
<connection_details env="dev">
  <servers>
    <server host="localhost" name="auth" port="9876"/>
  </servers>
</connection_details>
```

The issue manifests itself as every request returns the same as the initial request, even if the environment variable passed into the GET request changes.  This is even if requested from different browsers and soapUI.

Example of how the response above is created:

```
private ModelAndView bootstrap(HttpServletResponse response, String environment) { 

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(documentBuilder.parse(context
                    .getResourceAsStream(bootstrapXmlFileName)));

            model.put("xml", domSource);
            model.put("requestedEnvironment", environment);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            response.setHeader("ERRORS", e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return null;
        }

        return new ModelAndView("bootstrap_connection_selector", model);
    }
```

Then it is passed to an xslt transformation:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/xsl/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xslt" />

    </bean>
```

Finally the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <!-- parameter for the requested location --> 
        <xsl:param name="requestedlocation"/>
        <!-- start template matching on the connection_details element -->  
        <xsl:template match="/connection_details">

        <!-- duplicate the enclosing <connection_details env=xxx" element -->
        <xsl:element name="connection_details">
            <xsl:attribute name="env">
                <xsl:value-of select="@env"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            ...

        <!-- close the <connection_details> element -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

server.xml:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8133" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/> 
  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

  </GlobalNamingResources> 
  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8130" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8131"/>

    <Connector port="8132" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8131"/>


    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="em_bootstrap" path="/bootstrap" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:em_bootstrap"> 
      </Context></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Can you show how you produce the response and what it is?

Comment: Added details above on the response.

Comment: I'm more interested in the process of creating it.

Comment: Additional details above - the xslt transformation may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bad case of not checking the Filters.  There was a caching filter applied in the web.xml, probably the only place I didn't check.  It was incorrectly using the request.getRequestURI as the key for the cache, when in reality it needed the entire request string to properly place it in the cache.

Thanks